# How to get Preloaded Actor state in Service Fabric

Tags: azure-service-fabric

I am developing an application on Azure Service fabric. Its a simple User TODO application. I created TodoActor to add User TODO. It simply adds the User TODO using `StateManager`. I am aware that the StateManager will store the State in disk memory and not in any database.

But before starting the Application, I want that user should have preloaded Todos for them. Is there any way to have preloaded States for actor?

Is there any way to have this data in Database?

Answer (score 0):

Actors [are created](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-reliable-actors-lifecycle) when they are used. So for example, when it is called, or when a reminder triggers. If an Actor was never used before, it doesn't exist yet, so there is no way to pre-load state.

What you can do is pre-load data just-in-time when the Actor is created:

```
protected override async Task OnAactivateAsync()
{
   if(!await StateManager.ContainsStateAsync("ToDoState"))
   {
      await this.StateManager.TryAddStateAsync<List<string>>("ToDoState", new List<string>{});
   }

}
```